# Event title suggestion

Tags: synonyms, titles

I'm looking for an event title for a reception at which an organisation will introduce itself to the attendees. It will be an informal drinks reception.

At the moment the working title is: "XYZ Organisation Drinks Reception".

However, this doesn't really say what the event will be about. Are there any better suggestions? For example, "XYZ Organisation Introduces Itself" – any better wording would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The key word that I would keep is *reception*. This succintly characterizes the type of event. The word *drinks* is implied and adds no additional semantic value.

It appears that you would like to give your prospective attendees an idea of what the purpose of the reception is. There are many avenues you could take, but perhaps consider something like:

- XYZ Organisation Introductory Reception
- XYZ Organisation Welcoming Reception
- XYZ Organisation Initial Reception
- XYZ Organisation Opening Reception
- XYZ Organisation Inaugural Reception
- XYZ Organisation Kick Off Reception

EDIT: Given the context of an established neighborhood church in a financial district, the following suggestions are added:

Perhaps you can consider additional phrases such as:

- Organisation XYZ Meet & Greet
- Organisation XYZ Community Mixer
- Organisation XYZ Neighborhood Reception
- Organisation XYZ Community Reception
- Organisation XYZ Community Outreach Reception

Given that it's a church, you could also jazz it up and give it a fun title, like:

- Organisation XYZ "Neighborhood Joy" Reception
- Organisation XYZ "Good Neighbor" Reception
- Organisation XYZ "Love your neighbor as yourself" Reception

In a less formal setting I would suggest phrases like "Meet Your Community Night," but in a financial district that might be too informal.

Comment: Thanks, that are helpful comments. It's an established church in a financial district. So, it's not an inauguration. The purpose is to introduce the church to anyone who done't know it yet – either that it exists at all or what it does. So, it's an informal 'find out about' event. I believe that someone will give a speech/presentation but that a lot of time will just be taken up with people chatting over drinks. I reckon that most people in this category would come along because they have been invited by someone who's connected to the church. Happy to hear any further thoughts. Many thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer to include additional suggestions based on your feedback. Good luck!